# How to populate a record's geolocation within Salesforce1?

Tags: salesforce1-app, custom-object, geolocation

I'm working in a developing nation in a social work context, so traditional addresses don't exist so we use GPS cords.

How would I capture geolocation data within the Salesforce1 from the user's device to update a record that I'm viewing within SF1 app?  I found this post:  [navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition fails in Visualforce page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/89773/navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-fails-in-visualforce-page)

But I'm a bit uncertain as to how it specifically applies to SF1.  This would be something that we would only use via SF1 app on mobile device.

Visualforce page?  Quickaction?  Component?